# Need to get an average of a dictionary Key from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, average

I have a JSON file with this format:

```
{
    "people":    [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "age":19,
            "member": false
        },
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "age": 23,
            "member": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Michael Johnson",
            "age":19,
            "member": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Daniel Katz",
            "age":17,
            "member": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to load it as a Python object and calculate the age average. However, any For loop I tried running on this file after opening the file resulted in some sort of TypeError. Any suggestions on how to perform this?

```html
import json
with open('students.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data_people = data['people']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) on your dictionary:

```
import json
from statistics import mean

with open('students.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

avg_age = mean(p['age'] for p in data['people'])
```

output: `19.5`

Answer (score 0):

get list of peoples and use sum on its `age` key:

```python
import json


text = """{
    "people":    [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "age": 19,
            "member": false
        },
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "age": 23,
            "member": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Michael Johnson",
            "age": 19,
            "member": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Daniel Katz",
            "age": 17,
            "member": false
        }
    ]
}"""

data = json.loads(text)
# or
# with open('students.json') as f:
#    data = json.load(f)


average = lambda l: sum(map(lambda x: x["age"], l ))/ len(l)
print(average(data["people"]))
```

output: `19.5`

Comment: While your combination of nested lambdas, `sum` and `map` is very clever, mozway's answer is more Pythonic in character. It is *explicit*, *simple*, *flat* and *readable*. Although the  [Zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) was originally meant to be about the design of Python, it is not a bad guiding principle for writing python code.